# Namespace issue with Concrete5 Express List on Single Page

Tags: php, class, express, namespaces, concrete5

I'm trying to follow the tutorial for retrieving express entries as per this link:

https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/express/creating-read...

However, I'm greeted with the following error message:

"Class 'Application\Controller\SinglePage\Concrete\Core\Express\EntryList' not found"

My code is as follows:

```
<?php  
namespace Application\Controller\SinglePage;
use PageController;
use Express;
class Search extends PageController
{
    private $cruise;
    public function view()
    {
        $entity = Express::getObjectByHandle('cruise');
        $list = new Concrete\Core\Express\EntryList($entity);
        $results = $list->getResults();
        $this->set('results', $results);
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
$list = new Concrete\Core\Express\EntryList($entity);
```

You can either do:

```
$list = new \Concrete\Core\Express\EntryList($entity); // Notice the backslash
```

Or you can import the EntryList class:

```
<?php  
namespace Application\Controller\SinglePage;
use PageController;
use Express;
use Concrete\Core\Express\EntryList;

class Search extends PageController
{
    private $cruise;
    public function view()
    {
        $entity = Express::getObjectByHandle('cruise');
        $list = new EntryList($entity);
        $results = $list->getResults();
        $this->set('results', $results);
    }
}
```